# Datetime column in dataframe is preventing me from writing to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe containing data in five columns. A sample of the dataframe is at the bottom of my post. The first column is all date times (first row is 2017-05-26 19:00:00 for formatting example). I have the below code for writing to excel, which works when I exclude the datetime column.

```
dat = well_dat

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('CFW1_HOBO_20170526_20170719.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter', datetime_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')

dat.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

well_dat is a dataframe in this code. I first tried without including the date_time format, but neither method has worked.

I receive this error when I try to run the code

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any information or assistance would be helpful, thanks!

```
Date Time  w_press Abs Pres (kPa)  w_temp_C Temp (�C)  \
0 2017-05-26 19:00:00               -9999.000           -9999.000   
1 2017-05-26 19:15:00               -9999.000           -9999.000   
2 2017-05-26 19:30:00                  98.085              23.004   
3 2017-05-26 19:45:00                  98.105              22.333   
4 2017-05-26 20:00:00                 158.635              13.942   
5 2017-05-26 20:15:00                 158.602              11.236   

   atmosphere Abs Pres Barom. (kPa)  Sensor Depth (meters)  
0                            98.296              -9999.000  
1                            98.288              -9999.000  
2                            98.315              -9999.000  
3                            98.312              -9999.000  
4                            98.318                  6.156  
5                            98.325                  6.150
```

Comment: [`0xb0` is the degree sign](https://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/176/en). That's where your trouble is coming from. Just remove that from your column name and you'll be good.

Comment: This was it, thank you!